# How to animate just a single marker in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have designed Google Map aspx page showing multiple locations in the form of markers. The page appears as a pop-up from another aspx page. That another aspx page is having one drop-down control from where the user selects the preferred branch-locations. The branch-locations are being coming from the database. The requirement is just to animate a single marker in Google map pop-up window, which the user selects from drop down control from previous aspx page. How to animate a single marker ?

What could be the solution for that ? Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score -1):

Here is the documentation on animating a marker:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#MarkerAnimations

You can set the animation at the time of marker creation, or you can call setAnimation() on the Marker object after it's already part of the map.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your reply,, but i have used the following under for loop which iterates that number of times for which there are total branch locations ---                                                   function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}                                                                          But still all markers gets animated as soon as we click on them. I want only one marker to get animated on-load itself...